# Extend Class second time sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've extended my utility/class in Sencha Touch 2, now I want to extend it again by different type such that by different settings in config object.
Ive extended it again but when it is extended just (by just adding `extend: 'Ext.ux.MyUX'` again) it returns the previious settings in the previous object, but I want to handle it totally differently.
How can I remove the previous extended class or empty that `items[]`.

```
Ext.define('MyAPP.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.MyUX',
    xtype: 'my',
});
```

**My Code:**

```
initialize: function() {
var items = [
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title:'title'
        }];
this.setItems(items);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Lets say, I've a following config object extending my `Ext.ux.MyUX`. for the first instance its working perfectly, extending my class and override the `items[]` but when I want to extend it again, such that for different overriding, it shows the previous `items[]` that overrided/extended previously.

```
config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        items : [
        {
            title: 'Home'
        },
        {
            title: 'ABOUT',
            items: [{
                items: [
                { xtype: 'about'},
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'About Us',
                docked: 'top'
            }]
            }]
        }

        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you post full code of the base and extension classes?

Comment: @Saki A simple config of `Ext.ux` of items can be taken.

Comment: From the description alone, I have no idea what you want to achieve and what is the problem. So I hope I understand from the code.

Comment: @Saki please have a view on edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having `items` in a class prototype is not a very good idea even if you don't plan to extend the class further. Complex variables from prototype are shared by all instances that inevitably leads to troubles if you have more than one instance.

Be you I'd create a base class that would contain all functionality needed by descendants and I'd extend that:

```
B -> C
B -> D
```

instead of

```
B -> C -> D
```

Descendants would implement items as needed.

Comment: I'm currently doing as `Ext.ux.myUX-> MYAPP.view.View1`, `Ext.ux.myUX-> MYAPP.view.View2` but when I do the second extend, it shows the previous items.

Comment: is there any way to remove the extending view?

Comment: That's fine but do not implement items in `Ext.ux.myUX` but in views. The other option would be to use a [factory function](http://extjs.eu/?s=factory+function).

Comment: my above explains that `MYAPP.view.View1` extending `Ext.ux.myUX` and similarly the other one. Is that not true/fine?

Comment: The problem is not in extending, the problem is complex variables (objects, arrays) in a prototype - in this case, items. Complex variables are passed by reference hence all instances share same items, that is usually not what we want.

Comment: OK, now What I'm defining in `MYAPP.view.View1` `xtype:'about'` lets say, not this is not required in View2, what to do and how to handle if acording to your suggestion, I'll define my items directly in `Ext.ux.myUX`

Answer (score 0):

There's a really helpful article about how to extend classes with config objects:
http://skirtlesden.com/articles/config-objects-on-the-prototype

If this doesn't help I suggest to follow Saki's question for a full source code example. E.g. it's not obvious where you implemented the initialize function and which class you derived from.